# Spring cloud config doesn't detect git uri

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

How do I reference `resources` directory (Or a directory relative to my source files) as my local git uri for the config server (On Windows)?

I've tried `file:///resources` and `file:///full/path/to/resources`, all seem to fail.

As requested, here's some code:

ConfigServiceApplication.java

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///full/path/to/resources
spring.application.name=config-service
server.port=8888
```

Comment: maybe show some your code.. not sure about your problem

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: ok, i understand your problem, basically you can't do that, because you don't have .git directory there, you need a real REPO for that, spring cloud is not looking for config files, but REPO!

Comment: I have set up the directory as a repo with git init, and comitted the files.

Comment: first you have to do is configure it to another folder with e.g. `file://tmp/config-repo`, see if it works at all.. i'm not sure it supports git submodules.. so please try this first..

Comment: Who said anything about submodule? I've tried other folders aswell to no avail.

Comment: so your source code is not under git.. notice you need `file://` for *nix system and `file:///` for windows system

Comment: Please read the question. It clearly states `file:///`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to write this but intellij wouldn't clean the build. I ran the gradle task and it all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use file system as a backend, simply try this settings:

```
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: file:///full/path/to/resources
```

See also [this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_file_system_backend)